# CSS3 Flexible Box Layout and overflow: auto;

Tags: html, firefox, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a flexible box layout that fills the entire viewport, and has inner sections that scroll if the content is too long. However the inner content is stretching out the entire layout rather than sitting within the smaller area and scrolling.

I have a demo set up here with further details: http://jsbin.com/ezazig (Firefox only)

The `height: 100%;` isn't the problem, even if I give `.layout` a fixed height of 500px it's still ignored.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using CSS3 flexible box layout.  You're using XUL layout, which is quite different in terms of how it behaves.  That's really the main problem....

Comment: I am? According to this guide http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/ (which is what I followed), I'm using "The CSS 3 Flexible Box Model". Unless that article's wrong?

Comment: The article was correct as of 2010.  But you're making the incorrect assumption that `-moz-box` is a prefixed implementation of the 2010-era CSS3 draft.  In reality, `-moz-box` predates that draft by a decade or so.  The 2010-era draft was loosely based on it, but as I said quite different.  This has been clarified since 2010 by changing the display type the CSS Flexbox model will use from `box` to `flexbox`; the general set of properties it uses to control the behavior is also somewhat different.  Just compare http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/ to the article you mentioned.

Comment: Oh, and note that the article you read does link to the current TR version of the spec, which is actually up to date for once and also completely disagrees with the article.

Comment: Ah, OK. I was aware the implementation described had been superseded, but had no idea the FF implementation was actually a completely different layout system. Thanks for the clarification.

To my knowledge FF has not yet implemented the new flexbox proposal, so it looks like I'm ditching it for now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, the new layout system is coming but not there yet; see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=666041